# Android activity state (/stack) corrupted after update

Tags: android, xamarin

Consider version v1:

```
Start -> Activity A (noHistory=true) -> Activity B (noHistory=true)
Press home button
```

(verified with `noHistory=false` for both)

Install v2 by simply dragging the apk to the simulator or opening via dropbox.

```
Open the app
```

The application first hangs for a few seconds. Then I see my activity A with some text fields and buttons without any text in them. Without doing anything after a few seconds, it would say 'Application stopped working' and it would quit.

Any subsequent run would start from Activity A perfectly.

(Tested for simulators, as well as devices)

I am not sure as to why this is happening. I have seen other threads about this but they usually talk about incorrect stack; in my case the application stops responding after doing weird things (as described above).

Any pointers?

Comment: is there a stacktrace?

Comment: can you please let me know how I can get that for you? I have the release versions running on the simulator.

Comment: in your IDE, is there a place where your output prints the error when the application crashes

Comment: I am not running through the IDE. I am trying to see logs from `adb`. Further, I don't know when the application crashes.

Comment: if your on mac try running adb logcat | grep { application name } if you can get the logcat it would be very helpful

Comment: @inner_class7 thank you for `logcat`; saw main UI thread being jammed because of an infinite loop in an extremely rare migration case. Please provide an answer so I can close this. :)